# Ebay api return category list

Tags: c#

I have the following method that returns ebay item data from the api using item id. But the problem is I want to retrieve the ebay category and sub category lists using this [ebay documentation](https://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/reference/ebay/GetCategories.html). I have changed the following value to `GetCategories` instead of `GetMultipleItems` but it just messed it up and doesn't return anything. If anyone has a good idea about the ebay api then please help. My goal is return all ebay categories and subcategories, that's it. Thanks in advance. Note: I have put my test ebay account credentials just to help you debug quickly.

> request.Headers.Add("X-EBAY-API-CALL-NAME", "GetMultipleItems");

```
private string GetItemData(string itemID)
{

    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://open.api.ebay.com/shopping");
    byte[] bytes = null;
    request.Headers.Add("X-EBAY-API-APP-ID", "KavinHim-BestProd-PRD-78e3e6bf1-97d9ef25");
    request.Headers.Add("X-EBAY-API-DEV-NAME", "afd260f4-ec61-49e9-a78e-235d6a622c08");
    request.Headers.Add("X-EBAY-API-CERT-NAME", "PRD-8e3e6bf1d032-6b7b-44e2-abf5-e1a5");
    request.Headers.Add("X-EBAY-API-SITE-ID", "0");
    request.Headers.Add("X-EBAY-API-CALL-NAME", "GetMultipleItems");
    request.Headers.Add("X-EBAY-API-VERSION", "863");
    request.Headers.Add("X-EBAY-API-REQUEST-ENCODING", "xml");


    request.Timeout = Timeout.Infinite;
    request.KeepAlive = true;

    string itemNode = "<ItemID>" + itemID + "</ItemID> \n";

    bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?> <GetMultipleItemsRequest xmlns='urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents'> <IncludeSelector>ItemSpecifics</IncludeSelector> " + itemNode + " </GetMultipleItemsRequest>");

    request.Method = "POST";
    request.Proxy = null;


    Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
    requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    requestStream.Close();
    using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    {
        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            string responseStr = new StreamReader(responseStream).ReadToEnd();
            responseStream.Close();
            //var document = XDocument.Parse(responseStr);
            //XNamespace ns = "urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents";
            return responseStr;

        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: GetMultipleItems and GetCategories expects different inputs, did you change them?

Comment: No i didn't found the clear documentation which explains mandatory required fields @ZivWeissman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*1. XML API* .
Pay attention to url and header parameters i use in my sample. how to get ebay_token check this link http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/howto/tokens/gettingtokens.html

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create("https://api.sandbox.ebay.com/ws/api.dll");
request.Headers.Add("X-EBAY-API-APP-NAME", "stackove-testapp-SBX-95d7a0307-15c60ef4");
request.Headers.Add("X-EBAY-API-DEV-NAME", "ca7a53e9-b281-4787-a77c-91c73fb09e1f");
request.Headers.Add("X-EBAY-API-CERT-NAME", "SBX-5d7a030717dc-d70b-45b7-ab25-0c14");
request.Headers.Add("X-EBAY-API-SITEID", "0");
request.Headers.Add("X-EBAY-API-CALL-NAME", "GetCategories");
request.Headers.Add("X-EBAY-API-COMPATIBILITY-LEVEL", "863");
request.ContentType = "text/xml";
request.Method = "POST";
request.KeepAlive = true;
request.Proxy = null;

var eBayToken = "ebay_token";
var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(string.Format(@"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
    <GetCategoriesRequest xmlns='urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents'>
    <RequesterCredentials>
    <eBayAuthToken>{0}</eBayAuthToken>
    </RequesterCredentials>
    <CategorySiteID>0</CategorySiteID>
    <DetailLevel>ReturnAll</DetailLevel>
    </GetCategoriesRequest>", eBayToken));
request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    using (var response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse())
    {
        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            string responseStr = new StreamReader(responseStream).ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}
```

*2. ebay sdk for .net*

```
 eBay.Service.Call.GetCategoriesCall getCategories = new GetCategoriesCall();
            getCategories.ApiContext.SoapApiServerUrl = "https://api.sandbox.ebay.com/wsapi";
            getCategories.ApiContext.ApiCredential.eBayToken = your_token;
            getCategories.CategorySiteID = "0";
            getCategories.LevelLimit = 4;
            getCategories.DetailLevelList.Add(DetailLevelCodeType.ReturnAll);
            var categories = getCategories.GetCategories();
```